# Iterator adapter that counts repeated characters

Tags: string, count, char, rust, monads

I have a string like "aaaabbbccccc". I would like to create an adapter over a string's `chars` iterator that yields the counts of identical characters. The output (`count`) needs to be the number of consecutive identical characters. For instance:

```
let s = "aaaabbbccccc"
for count in s.chars().MAGIC() {
    println!("{}", count)
}
// prints: 4, 3, 5
```

Update: This almost works: the past does not consider the letter:

```
let s = "aaaabbbcccccdd".to_string();
let mut tt = (s.chars().nth(0).unwrap(), 0);
for a in s.chars().filter_map(|x| {
    if x != tt.0 {
        tt.0 = x;
        let tt_temp = tt.1;
        tt.1 = 1;
        Some(tt_temp)
    } else {
        tt.1 += 1;
        None
    }
}) {
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Comment: Identical sequential characters - this. Now I try to implement through a `filter_map()` using an external variable to store the previous character. The method can not be called elegant.

Answer (score 7):

Using [itertools'](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) [`.coalesce()`](https://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.coalesce) you can do it like this:

```
// Map each char to an initial count of 1, then merge counts for identical chars
.map(|c| (c, 1)).coalesce(|(c, n), (d, m)|
    if c == d { Ok((c, n + m)) } else { Err(((c, n), (d, m))) })
```

Answer (score 4):

Using only the standard library:

```
use std::iter::Peekable;

struct SequentialCount<I>
    where I: Iterator
{
    iter: Peekable<I>,
}

impl<I> SequentialCount<I>
    where I: Iterator
{
    fn new(iter: I) -> Self {
        SequentialCount { iter: iter.peekable() }
    }
}

impl<I> Iterator for SequentialCount<I>
    where I: Iterator,
          I::Item: Eq
{
    type Item = (I::Item, usize);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        // Check the next value in the inner iterator
        match self.iter.next() {
            // There is a value, so keep it
            Some(head) => {
                // We've seen one value so far
                let mut count = 1;
                // Check to see what the next value is without
                // actually advancing the inner iterator
                while self.iter.peek() == Some(&head) {
                    // It's the same value, so go ahead and consume it
                    self.iter.next();
                    count += 1;
                }
                // The next element doesn't match the current value 
                // complete this iteration 
                Some((head, count))
            }
            // The inner iterator is complete, so we are also complete
            None => None,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = "aaaabbbccccc";

    for (char, count) in SequentialCount::new(s.chars()) {
        println!("{} occurs {} times", char, count)
    }
}
```

Of course, you could do the usual work to create an *extension trait* to add a method on the iterator:

```
trait SequentialCountAdapter: Iterator {
    fn sequential_count(self) -> SequentialCount<Self>
        where Self: Sized
    {
        SequentialCount::new(self)
    }
}

impl<I> SequentialCountAdapter for I where I: Iterator {}
```

Comment: @ArtemGr aren't you just implementing `Peekable` yourself there? Is there a benefit to doing that?

Comment: With inlining the difference should be neglible. Without inlining the non-Peekable version might be faster. There might be educational value to see the different implementations of the same thing.