# How can I intersperse a rust iterator with a value every n items?

Tags: rust, iterator, rust-itertools

I have an iterator of characters, and I want to add a newline every N characters:

```
let iter = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".chars();
let iter_with_newlines = todo!();
let string: String = iter_with_newlines.collect();
assert_eq("abcdefghij\nklmnopqrst\nuvwxyz", string);
```

So basically, I want to intersperse the iterator with a newline every n characters. How can I do this?

### Some Ideas I had

It would be great if I could do something like this, where `chunks` would be a method to make `Iterator<T>` into `Iterator<Iterator<T>`: `iter.chunks(10).intersperse('\n').flatten()`

It would also be cool if I could do something like this: `iter.chunks.intersperseEvery(10, '\n')`, where `intersperseEvery` is a method that would only intersperse the value every n items.

Comment: Please don't insert the answer in the question. Instead you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 5):

You can do it without temporary allocation using `enumerate` and `flat_map`:

```
use either::Either;

fn main() {
    let iter = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".chars();
    let iter_with_newlines = iter
        .enumerate()
        .flat_map(|(i, c)| {
            if i % 10 == 0 {
                Either::Left(['\n', c].into_iter())
            } else {
                Either::Right(std::iter::once(c))
            }
        })
        .skip(1); // The above code add a newline in first position -> skip it
    let string: String = iter_with_newlines.collect();
    assert_eq!("abcdefghij\nklmnopqrst\nuvwxyz", string);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3b61e10083bc6621f64b8b4ba5f75d21)

Comment: Oh neat. I was confused about why `flat_map` worked here because I thought there's two levels (I was thinking of `Either<some Iterator, some Iterator>`) and `flat_map` should flatten only one. But [`Either impl Iterator`](https://docs.rs/either/latest/either/enum.Either.html#impl-Iterator-for-Either%3CL%2C%20R%3E). That's a trick that should help avoid mucking around with `Box<dyn …>` in quite a few situations when returning different types from an `if`.

Comment: `Either::Left` / `Either::Right` converts the inner value to an iterator. I see this for the first time. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```rust
// src/intersperse_sparse.rs

use core::iter::Peekable;

/// An iterator adaptor to insert a particular value
/// every n elements of the adapted iterator.
///
/// Iterator element type is `I::Item`
pub struct IntersperseSparse<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: Clone,
{
    iter: Peekable<I>,
    step_length: usize,
    index: usize,
    separator: I::Item,
}

impl<I> IntersperseSparse<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: Clone,
{
    #[allow(unused)] // Although this function isn't explicitly exported, it is called in the default implementation of the IntersperseSparseAdapter, which is exported.
    fn new(iter: I, step_length: usize, separator: I::Item) -> Self {
        if step_length == 0 {
            panic!("Chunk size cannot be 0!")
        }
        Self {
            iter: iter.peekable(),
            step_length,
            separator,
            index: 0,
        }
    }
}

impl<I> Iterator for IntersperseSparse<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: Clone,
{
    type Item = I::Item;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index == self.step_length && self.iter.peek().is_some() {
            self.index = 0;
            Some(self.separator.clone())
        } else {
            self.index += 1;
            self.iter.next()
        }
    }
}

/// An iterator adaptor to insert a particular value created by a function
/// every n elements of the adapted iterator.
///
/// Iterator element type is `I::Item`
pub struct IntersperseSparseWith<I, G>
where
    I: Iterator,
    G: FnMut() -> I::Item,
{
    iter: Peekable<I>,
    step_length: usize,
    index: usize,
    separator_closure: G,
}

impl<I, G> IntersperseSparseWith<I, G>
where
    I: Iterator,
    G: FnMut() -> I::Item,
{
    #[allow(unused)] // Although this function isn't explicitly exported, it is called in the default implementation of the IntersperseSparseAdapter, which is exported.
    fn new(iter: I, step_length: usize, separator_closure: G) -> Self {
        if step_length == 0 {
            panic!("Chunk size cannot be 0!")
        }
        Self {
            iter: iter.peekable(),
            step_length,
            separator_closure,
            index: 0,
        }
    }
}

impl<I, G> Iterator for IntersperseSparseWith<I, G>
where
    I: Iterator,
    G: FnMut() -> I::Item,
{
    type Item = I::Item;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index == self.step_length && self.iter.peek().is_some() {
            self.index = 0;
            Some((self.separator_closure)())
        } else {
            self.index += 1;
            self.iter.next()
        }
    }
}

/// Import this trait to use the `iter.intersperse_sparse(n, item)` and `iter.intersperse_sparse(n, ||item)` on all iterators.
pub trait IntersperseSparseAdapter: Iterator {
    fn intersperse_sparse(self, chunk_size: usize, separator: Self::Item) -> IntersperseSparse<Self>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        Self::Item: Clone,
    {
        IntersperseSparse::new(self, chunk_size, separator)
    }

    fn intersperse_sparse_with<G>(
        self,
        chunk_size: usize,
        separator_closure: G,
    ) -> IntersperseSparseWith<Self, G>
    where
        Self: Sized,
        G: FnMut() -> Self::Item,
    {
        IntersperseSparseWith::new(self, chunk_size, separator_closure)
    }
}

impl<I> IntersperseSparseAdapter for I where I: Iterator {}
```

To use it:

```rust
// src/main.rs

mod intersperse_sparse;
use intersperse_sparse::IntersperseSparseAdapter;

fn main() {
    let string = "abcdefg";
    let new_string: String = string.chars().intersperse_sparse(3, '\n').collect();
    assert_eq!(new_string, "abc\ndef\ng");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't particularly care about performance, you can use `chunks` from `itertools`, collect the chunks into `Vec`s, and then intersperse your element as a single-element `Vec`, just to flatten the whole thing finally.

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;
iter
    .chunks(3)
    .into_iter()
    .map(|chunk| chunk.collect::<Vec<_>>())
    .intersperse(vec![','])
    .flat_map(|chunk| chunk.into_iter())
    .collect::<String>();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=16ea6a944fc8216ac892b6381c860590)

Other than that, consider writing your own iterator extension trait, just like itertools is one?

Comment: How could I write my own iterator extension trait?

Comment: Stackoverflow has quite a few examples for that. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702386/iterator-adapter-that-counts-repeated-characters/32718099#32718099) seems decently easy to understand (though you won't need `Peekable` or the content of the `next` function there)?

Comment: Here's what I ended up making: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0bdf4ca6e0e491229ed7d9f5030dda4d).

What do you think of the names I chose for the module, structs, and trait? Do you think something else would be more clear?

Answer (score 1):

Build an `Iterator` with `from_fn`:

```
let mut iter = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".chars().peekable();
let mut count = 0;
let iter_with_newlines = std::iter::from_fn(move || match iter.peek() {
    Some(_) => {
        if count < 10 {
            count += 1;
            iter.next()
        } else {
            count = 0;
            Some('\n')
        }
    }
    None => None,
});
assert_eq!(
    "abcdefghij\nklmnopqrst\nuvwxyz",
    iter_with_newlines.collect::<String>()
);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=97639b5a26d536610be7027e9463bd7d)